# Python Modules simply won't install

Tags: python, module

Okay. So I have been trying a lot lately to install python modules. They won't install. Yes, I have set the path. And yes, I tried almost everything already on this website. I have Python 3.6.0 and Windows 10.

For instance, this is what it says when I ask the cmd to install numpy. 
It basically says Atlas not supported, atlas not found. LAPACK not supported or found. And probably a thousand other things. Its really frustrating. If someone could help please. 
      [Look this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXzfd.png)
      [And this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DBUj.png)

Comment: have you tried to install some thing other then numpy?

Comment: If you're on Windows it's really much simpler to download the binaries from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) and install that way.

Comment: Yeah I tried matplotlib, panda etc. nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your are trying to install **numpy** or a numpy dependency from source. So the installer tries to compile from C source code. This is not an easy task under Windows, since you need to install the whole tool chain.

You need to install the wheel package that matches both your platform/OS but also your Python version.

According to the official [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy), there is no binary distribution for Python 3.6 (except for Mac OS X).

The solution is to downgrade to Python 3.5.

Note: consider using a recent version of **pip** to install packages.

Comment: There's a binary for 3.6 in my comment on the question so I don't think that's going to help.

Comment: @roganjosh There is no Python 3.6 wheel for Windows on the official PyPi.

Comment: But in theory the OP could get it from the site I gave, which would be preferable to downgrading Python itself? Honestly, trying to install numpy on Windows is just horrible, I don't think it's worth trying anything other than going for the unofficial binaries.

Comment: Okay. So numpy got installed after installing C++ tool pack, but matplotlib won't install.